# Using Green's function to solve the Delta well potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, greens-functions

Can you use Green's function to solve the delta well potential problem from quantum mechanics? If so, how would you do that? Wouldn't the Green's function be the delta function?

Comment: I have a couple of QM text books, and there's no mention of Green's functions when solving the delta well. They do the discontinuity condition, taking a small neighborhood around the point where the well is.

Comment: Yes, my apologies  for omitting a link in my earlier comment. In a way, a delta function, in my view of things, is a limiting case of a Green's function.  http://ethesis.nitrkl.ac.in/7815/  is a paper that deals with Green's Functions and Delta potentials, but possibly designed  for  more  involved systems, such as a Dirac Comb. Please have a look at the paper, the abstract of which says  _This paper contains  detailed calculations to find the Greens function for single and double delta function potentials_

Comment: @CountTo10 Sorry, but did you check the quality of that paper you linked to? The section on Green's function for delta potential looks like a lift from https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9801033v2.pdf, which is listed in the refs. therein as ref.[4]  but without an actual arxiv or journal ref. (!!) Otoh, the reliable arxiv source comes up right away on a Google search.